# Sort result set based on count of occurrence value in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this dummy query that represents simplified version of actual query

```
SELECT 
s.s_name, 
p.p_name, 
p.department_id 
FROM students s 
INNER JOIN professors p 
ON s.professor_id = p.id;
```

I want to sort the result set based on number of times a certain department_id comes in the result set. If there are 6 rows total - 1 for d1, 2 for d2 and 3 for d3. Then, all the rows with d3 should come on top, then d2 and then d1.

This is current result set:

```
s_name         | p_name         | department_id
s1             | p1             | d1
s2             | p2             | d2
s3             | p3             | d3
s4             | p4             | d3
s5             | p5             | d2
s6             | p6             | d3
```

This is what I want:

```
s_name         | p_name         | department_id
s3             | p3             | d3
s4             | p4             | d3
s6             | p6             | d3
s2             | p2             | d2
s5             | p5             | d2
s1             | p1             | d1
```

**Note:** FYI, In above example I have only mentioned s_name and p_name, but in actual there are lots of columns and tables from where data is coming, so I want to avoid group by + count combo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions in the `order by`:

```
order by count(*) over (partition by p.department_id),
         p.department_id,
         p.p_name
```

Note that the second key ensures that rows for a given department are all together even when another department has the same number of rows.